# packing numbers and configuration spaces of the torus

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, packing-and-covering, configuration-spaces, sphere-packing

Let $S^1$  be  the  unit circle of  radius $1$.

For any $k\geq 1$,  let  the $k$-dimensional torus $T^k=  \underbrace{S^1\times S^1\times\cdots\times S^1}_k$  be      the  $k$-fold self-Cartesian product of $S^1$.

Equip $T^k$  with the product Riemannian metric.

For any real number  $r>0$ and any integer $n\geq 1$,  consider the (ordered) disk configuration space

$$
F_r(T^k,n)=\Big\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in T^k~~\Big |~~ d(x_i,x_j)\geq  2r ~{\rm ~for~any~}~1\leq i<j\leq n \Big \}.
$$

Fix $r$ and $k$.

If $n$  is  large  enough,  then $F_r(T^k,n)=\emptyset$.

Denote the largest $n$  such that $F_r(T^k,n)\neq \emptyset$  by
$N(k,r)$.

**Question 1.**  *For any integer $k\geq 1$ and any real number  $r>0$, how to  compute $N(k,r)$?*

**Question 2.**  *For any real number  $r>0$, how to compute the limit $\lim_{k\to\infty }N(k,r)^{\frac{1}{k}}$?*

Are there any references?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How is the problem related to braid groups?

Comment: Hi Prof. I am not sure how they are related. @Mr.

Comment: How is this related to sphere packing in Euclidean space? For example, I imagine this can be answered for certain $k$ and $r$ by looking at periodic closely-packings of spheres in Euclidean space.

Answer (score 1):

If you rescale your circles to have circumference 2, then you are interested in packings of $N$ spheres in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space with periodicity $(2\mathbb{Z})^n$. The configuration space is usually written as $\mathbb{R}^n/(2\mathbb{Z})^n$, and the minimum distance between spheres, $2r$, would have the restriction $r\le 1$ so that the coset elements also respect the packing constraint. The parameter $r$ is the sphere radius.

For small $n$ and $r=1$ the maximum $N$ is achieved by Hamming distance 4 binary codes, where all the coordinates are 0 and 1. You can find the best known $N$ in the first column of the table on this website:

[https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/codes/binary-1.html](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/codes/binary-1.html)